# Blank page when Link from React-Router-Dom is added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I add the Link tag from react-router-dom the webpage doesn't show anything, i.e. the JavaScript is not loading in react.

Here is my code

```
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route,Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Checkout from './Components/Checkout';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Store from './Components/Store';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Link to="/store">store</Link>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path="/store" element={<Store/>} />
          <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout/>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The components all load properly when I prefix the site URL with their path, i.e. [www.mysite.org/store](http://www.mysite.org/store).

I am asking this because I wasn't able to find a thread with similar problem.

I am using react-router-dom V6.4.3

I have tried changing the path mentioned in the "to" to different formats but none worked.

Eg:

1. `<Link to = "/store">Store<Link/>`
2. `<Link to = "store">Store<Link/>`
3. `<Link to = "../store">Store<Link/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is outside the router, it needs to be rendered within a routing context.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/store">store</Link> // <-- inside router
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path="/store" element={<Store/>} />
          <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout/>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```